# Why does solder mask change color if there is underlying copper if it's green or blue but not white or black?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Soldermask on a PCB, which is some kind of UV-cured enamel, changes color drastically to a much more brilliant hue if there is a layer of copper directly underneath it if it's a green color. The same is true of blue, yellow or red soldermask. This can be convenient because it shows the underlying traces.

However, if the soldermask is white or black, the color does not change – it's still solid white or black.

Why is that? Is it because it shifts hue but white and black don't have a hue? Why does copper change the color of the overlaying enamel?

[image]

Comment: It's just not opaque unless it's white or black?  You probably could get opaque colored soldermask, but it'd probably be pastel.

Comment: they're definitely not opaque